# How to use conv1d to summarize a variable-length sentence?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, conv-neural-network, sentiment-analysis

I have a sentence that I want to "summarize" or classify using neural network.

Each word in the sentence is represented by a vector of size 16. I want to use a 1d convolution of a variable length sentence, and then classify.

When I use conv1d, I could not figure out how to feed words one after another and get any summary vector.

```
layer_1 = Conv1d(input_channel, output_channel, kernel = 3, stride=2) 
layer_2 = Conv1d(input_channel, output_channel, kernel = 3, stride=2) .. etc
```

Problem is, if loop throw the words of the sentence and make a tensor, then I cannot feed the network.

```
For example,
I am new to this. (5 words -- this is variable)

I    -> [2, 1, .... 16 numbers]
am   -> [5, 7, .... 16 numbers]
...
this -> [9, 1, .... 16 numbers]
```

Since, the length is variable, I (don't know) cannot feed to the Conv1d layer. And if I transpose it and set input_channel = 8, it will work, but it loses the meaning.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

The following perception doesn't work.

```
# input_data = torch.randn((batch_size, max_seq_length, embedding_dim))  
# conv1d = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=embedding_dim, out_channels=num_filters, kernel_size=filter_size)

#================+++=#
batch_size     = 1  # 1 Sentene at a time, or 8 
max_seq_length = 12 # 12 words 
embedding_dim  = 4  # Vect size 4 for each word

num_filters    = 1
filter_size    = 3

input_data = torch.randn((batch_size, max_seq_length, embedding_dim))  
conv1d = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=embedding_dim, out_channels=num_filters, kernel_size=filter_size)
```